# retreiving sqlite and firebase data at the same time

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, firebase

Im retrieving a UID from sqlite and using that uid to fetch data from firebase but the problem is its only fetching the values of the first UID and not after that

Code

```
  String userId = null;
            Cursor csr = myDBHlpr.getAllQuestions4();
            while (csr.moveToNext()) {
                userId = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_USER_ID));
            }
            final String uid = userId;


            mUsersDatabase.child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    mName = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                    String mStatus = dataSnapshot.child("Status").getValue().toString();
                    String mDisplayImage = dataSnapshot.child("Image").getValue().toString();

                    mUsers.add(new IdHelper(mName, mStatus, mDisplayImage));
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

The table has multiple rows with different UIDs and firebase too has multiple UID data... I have crosschecked multiple times. But still only the one item is fetched. Why is that? should i retrieve sqlite data is a string []?
Database ref is perfect and the problem according to me is that im fetching only one data as userid and im thinking it stops there so only one IDs data is getting fetched from firebase. Anyways can someone help me out please

Edit

```
    public Cursor getAllQuestions4() {
    return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_ID_DATA,null,null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

Comment: Could you show a definition of `myDBHlpr.getAllQuestions4();` method ?

Comment: Done @krokodilko....................

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is the while loop. You are only using the last userId. So change your code as follows (please notice the change of the last bracket of your while loop):

```
String userId = null;
Cursor csr = myDBHlpr.getAllQuestions4();

while (csr.moveToNext()) 
{
    userId = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_USER_ID));

    final String uid = userId;

    mUsersDatabase.child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            mName = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
            String mStatus = dataSnapshot.child("Status").getValue().toString();
            String mDisplayImage = dataSnapshot.child("Image").getValue().toString();

            mUsers.add(new IdHelper(mName, mStatus, mDisplayImage));
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: it still shows only the last UIDs data... i added new datas and checked and its showing only the last UIDs data

Comment: Can you debug your code and check what userIds you are receiving from your local database? Are all userIds present?

Comment: Yeah both IDs are present

Comment: Can u look through my code through teamviewer or something please? stuck here since a week so

Comment: No sorry, thats currently not possible.

Comment: alright any other possibiliteis for why its not working?

Comment: Try to debug your code. I would call the firebase method manually to check getting the right data (mUsersDatabase.child(*put your userId here*). If you are getting the right data, then it must be your local database (maybe wrong / differnet userIds?)